# Methods using arguments vs member variables

Tags: c++, methods, arguments

I am often wondering what is considered "better" when I write a class method and want to pass arguments to this method.

1. Option: using member variables

   ```
   class Foo {
       public:
           int x, y, result;

           void SomeMethod()
           {
               x = 4;
               y = 10;
               AddMethod();
           }

           void AddMethod()
           {
               result = x + y;
           }
   }
   ```
2. Option: passing arguments

   ```
   class Foo {
       public:
           int result;

           void SomeMethod()
           {
               result = AddMethod(4, 14);
           }

           int AddMethod(int x, int y)
           {
               return (x + y);
           }
   }
   ```

Personally I usually tend to use the second option, because to me it is more readable and comprehensible. What would be the correct reasoning to use one or the other code?

Comment: is it part of the state of the object or only used in the context of that single member function?

Comment: imho your example isnt the best, because for what you are doing I wouldnt write a class at all

Comment: There is no one answer to this kind of question. It all depends on the circumstances and you didn't show them. I understand this is because you want a general guideline for how to program, but there aren't any - you have to think and consider the situation in every case and make the decision based on the arguments.

Comment: @slawekwin Yes, I was looking for some general guideline. But "there is no general guideline to this", is also an answer, which helps me. Even thou the question most definitely does not have a very positive resonance, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class in OOP is something which describes an object. Take a real world object for example, a car. The car can have functions like `accelerate_to_speed(double speed);` and some members like `Color color;`. The methods are something the object does and the members describe the object or show possession (the car can have an engine `Engine engine;`). The whole concept of what is a member and what is a method lies at a foundation of object oriented programming and is not dependent upon language but the language is dependant upon it.

You could still write a class car in this way:

```
class Car {
    ...
    double target_speed;
    ...
    void set_target_speed(double speed) {
        target_speed = speed;
    }
    void accelerate_to_speed() {
        current_speed = target_speed;
    }
    ...
}
```

And the language would allow it but what does it mean? Is the car described by what the target speed is? What does the target speed mean if the car is not used?